# Problems with jQuery Resizable & Draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, image-resizing

I'm trying to build a really simple photo editing module using jQuery UI on our website's  products page, But I'm having a serious problem getting this thing done.

Issue I'm facing in first load everything works fine. But when I load a an image again, draggable is stop working, means dragging works but drop wont. So you cannot drop the image when you start dragging it. And the resize handle stays the same place as it was in the first image.

Below is my code (Some of it, which I reckon important)

**HTML**

```
<div id="pp-dlite-area">
<div id="dl-canvas">
    <div class="dl-design-mask">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="dl-photo-wrap">
        <img id="pp-dlite-photo-mask1" class="dl-photo" />
        <img id="pp-dlite-photo-image1" class="dl-photo-img dl-linked" />
        <img id="pp-dlite-photo-trans1" class="dl-photo-trans dl-linked" />
        <div class="dl-photo-trap dl-linked">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    ....
    ....

    //START RESIZE AND DRAG_DROP
    $j(".dl-photo").resizable({
        aspectRatio: true,
        resize: function () {
            $j(this).parent().find('.dl-linked').width($j(this).width());
            $j(this).parent().find('.dl-linked').height($j(this).height());
            $j(this).parent().find('.dl-photo-trans').css('zIndex', $j(this).parent().find('.dl-photo-trap').css('zIndex'));
        },
        stop: function () {
            $j(this).parent().find('.dl-photo-trans').css('zIndex', $j(this).parent().find('.dl-photo').css('zIndex'));
        }
    })
        .parent().draggable({
        containment: "#dl-canvas",
        drag: function () {
            $j(this).parent().find('.dl-linked').css('top', $j(this).css('top'));
            $j(this).parent().find('.dl-linked').css('left', $j(this).css('left'));
            $j(this).parent().find('.dl-photo-trans').css('zIndex', $j(this).parent().find('.dl-photo-trap').css('zIndex'));
        },
        stop: function () {
            $j(this).parent().find('.dl-linked').css('top', $j(this).css('top'));
            $j(this).parent().find('.dl-linked').css('left', $j(this).css('left'));
            $j(this).parent().find('.dl-photo-trans').css('zIndex', $j(this).parent().find('.dl-photo').css('zIndex'));
        }
    });

    $j(".dl-photo-trans").draggable({
        containment: "#dl-canvas"
    });

    $j(".dl-photo-img").draggable({
        containment: "#dl-canvas"
    });

   ......
   ......
   .....
```

Remember everything works fine first image load, its like some stuff doesn't get refreshed when images are loading after that :(

Please help since I'm working on this issue for last 2 days trying so many different stuff, but unsuccessful.

Comment: How are u loading the image again?

Comment: Through a file upload, I load the image to the server and refer it from there

Comment: Which server side r u using. The file upload using ajax, inst it?

Comment: I'm using strip down version of [jQuery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)